# What is a 7th chord and why is it important?

Tags: theory, chords, sevenths

What is a 7th chord and why is it important?   I keep seeing it over and over again and I don't understand why it's important?

Comment: A little more information is needed to give a good answer. Do you know what "intervals" are? And do you know what the "root" of a chord is?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, it would help to know if you are asking about 7th chords in general (there are a variety of different ones) or a specific 7th chord.

Answer (score 13):

They sound cool for one.  But there is more to it than that.

The "7th" chord, also called dominant 7th, is the following set of notes (1, 3, 5, b7) relative to the Major scale.  For example a C7 = (C, E, G, Bb).

In any key a 7th chord occurs naturally on the 5th degree.  If you take the notes (5, 7, 9, 11) or (5, 7, 2, 4) from the major scale of the key signature this is a 7th chord.  We denote it V7 to specify that its root is on the 5th degree.

For example, in the Key of C there is a 7th chord on G consisting of the following notes (G, B, D, F).

Where it arises is in chord progressions and specifically the authentic cadence, which is the movement V7 --> I, or in our example G7 --> C.  This has the strongest sense of completion of any chord change.  Within this movement there are 2 half steps moving in opposite direction, 7 --> 8 and 4 --> 3.  The interval (7, 4) or (4, 7) is a diminished 5th and the interval (3, 8) is a minor 6th, and (1, 3) is a major third.  This is the prime example of resolving dissonance into consonance.

For this reason it is one of the most important chords in Western harmony theory.  If you analyze oodles of classical music you will find V7 --> I all over the place.  There are other cadences like IV --> I, etc.  But V7 --> I is considered the strongest.

There are other 7th chords.  But the term X7 is reserved for the dominant 7th chord (1, 3, 5, b7).  You can put a maj or min 7 on any triad.  Examples are XMaj7 = (1, 3, 5, 7), Xmin7 = (1, b3, 5, b7), Xmin7(b5) = (1, b3, b5, b7), Xmin(Maj7) = (1, b3, 5, 7), etc.

The "7th" chord is used very often in the Blues where it likely occurs on every degree,

I7 IV7 I7 I7

IV7 IV7 I7 I7

V7 IV7 I7 V7

Comment: Sometimes you may also see 7th chord inversions, e.g. G/F (G over base F) is actually an inversion of G7, (F, G, B, D) instead of (G, B, D, F), which also sound great before the I chord.

Answer (score 1):

Chords in Western music are usually built from thirds. We start on one note of a scale (the root of the chord), go up a third and add that as the next note (the third of the chord), then go up another third and add that as the next note (the fifth of the chord)...

...and the most commony-mentioned kinds of chords, called 'triads', stop there, with three notes. Standard major and minor chords are examples of these.

...but you can keep going up: go up another interval of a third (from the fifth) and you end up adding the seventh, making a seventh chord. And you can add a ninth (making a ninth chord), eleventh... and so on.

ggcg's answer contains some excellent points about seventh chords, but perhaps one useful way of thinking about them is that there isn't really anything super special about seventh chords; they're simply the kind of chord that adds one more third than the triad, but one less than a ninth chord.